# FIrefox 16.0.2 Error: TypeError: parent is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, fckeditor

I have this function in my site and i'm getting the erorr
Error: TypeError: parent is undefined

is there another way to target the parent frames this worked fine until the upgrade

```
function MyClass() {
    this.UpdateEditorFormValue = function()  {
        for ( i = 0; i < parent.frames.length; ++i )
            if ( parent.frames[i].FCK )
                parent.frames[i].FCK.UpdateLinkedField();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `window.parent`? Just `parent` will look for a local variable called `parent`, not for the parent frame.

Comment: i don't want the window though i want the parent frame  which is the FCK editor

Comment: Well were do you define `parent`? It's not a global variable introduced by FCK editor.

Comment: isn't parent just the the triggering objects parent ?

Comment: No. JavaScript has no real classes and sub-classes, hence no inbuilt inheritance.

Comment: thats seems to work why don't you put that in as an answer ;)

Comment: What seems to work? My first comment? So you actually do want the frames window parent (the window that has the frame in it) and not the *parent* of the your class?

Comment: correct the first comment window.parent... dont' know how it worked before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `window.parent`? Just `parent` will look for a variable called `parent`, not for the parent frame.

Comment: It should look for the local variable, but then search for the global one if no local one exists.  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3WPf6/1/

Comment: True, I fixed it in the answer.